# Javascript Array Map 2D array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to aggregate the array (arr) below so that I get an output such as:

**Desired Output:** [['2011-04-11','Open',6],['2011-04-11','Closed',4]]

but I'm getting:
**Output:** [2011-04-11,Open: 6, 2011-04-11,Closed: 4]

How can I take the javascript array map and convert to desired out.

**Source code excerpt:**

```
var arr = [
    ['2011-04-11', 'Open'],
    ['2011-04-11', 'Closed'],
    ['2011-04-11', 'Closed'],
    ['2011-04-11', 'Open'],
    ['2011-04-11', 'Open'],
    ['2011-04-11', 'Open'],
    ['2011-04-11', 'Closed'],
    ['2011-04-11', 'Closed'],
    ['2011-04-11', 'Open'],
    ['2011-04-11', 'Open']
];

var hist = [];
arr.map(function(a) {
   if (a in hist)
      hist[a]++;
   else
      hist[a] = 1;
});
```

Comment: You don't need an extra array when you use `map`, just return something. Also you want to use `indexOf` not `in` when working with arrays. Otherwise use an object if your keys are not numeric.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`[].reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) instead:

```
var result = function() {
    var hist = {};

    return arr.reduce(function(previous, current) {
        if (current in hist) {
            previous[hist[current]][2]++;
        } else {
            previous[hist[current] = previous.length] = current.concat(1);
        }
        return previous;
    }, []);
}();
```

During the reduce operation, it uses `hist` to keep track of where each item can be found in the new array that's being built.

If the item already exists, it will increase its frequency element (third element). If the item does not yet exist, it will set its frequency to 1 and update `hist` to the position of the new item.

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/moqur/1/)

Comment: +1 Clever. I came up with `console.log(arr.reduce(function(tillNow, currentItem) {
    tillNow[currentItem] = (tillNow[currentItem] || 0) + 1;
    return tillNow;
}, {}));` and got stuck :'(